# PHP Laravel GraphQL Query Declaration Incompatibility issue

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

I followed the following article to setup laravel with graphql on my local machine:

https://auth0.com/blog/developing-and-securing-graphql-apis-with-laravel

I following the complete article step by step without any issue. But when I run my app using

```sh
php artisan serve
```

and hit the endpoint `localhost:8000/graphql`, I get the following error.

> [Sat Aug 31 23:09:20 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of App\GraphQL\Queries\WineQuery::type() must be compatible with 
>   Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Field::type(): GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type 
>   in /Users/sushilsingh/Projects/winestore/app/GraphQL/Queries/WineQuery.php on line 9

Here is my WineQuery.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use App\Wine;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;

class WineQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'wine',
    ];

    public function type()
    {
        return GraphQL::type('Wine');
    }

    public function args()
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'name' => 'id',
                'type' => Type::int(),
                'rules' => ['required']
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args)
    {
        return Wine::findOrFail($args['id']);
    }
}
```

Here is graphql.php

````php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use example\Type\ExampleType;
use example\Query\ExampleQuery;
use example\Mutation\ExampleMutation;
use example\Type\ExampleRelationType;

return [

    // The prefix for routes
    'prefix' => 'graphql',

    // The routes to make GraphQL request. Either a string that will apply
    // to both query and mutation or an array containing the key 'query' and/or
    // 'mutation' with the according Route
    //
    // Example:
    //
    // Same route for both query and mutation
    //
    // 'routes' => 'path/to/query/{graphql_schema?}',
    //
    // or define each route
    //
    // 'routes' => [
    //     'query' => 'query/{graphql_schema?}',
    //     'mutation' => 'mutation/{graphql_schema?}',
    // ]
    //
    'routes' => '{graphql_schema?}',

    // The controller to use in GraphQL request. Either a string that will apply
    // to both query and mutation or an array containing the key 'query' and/or
    // 'mutation' with the according Controller and method
    //
    // Example:
    //
    // 'controllers' => [
    //     'query' => '\Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQLController@query',
    //     'mutation' => '\Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQLController@mutation'
    // ]
    //
    'controllers' => \Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQLController::class.'@query',

    // Any middleware for the graphql route group
    'middleware' => [],

    // Additional route group attributes
    //
    // Example:
    //
    // 'route_group_attributes' => ['guard' => 'api']
    //
    'route_group_attributes' => [],

    // The name of the default schema used when no argument is provided
    // to GraphQL::schema() or when the route is used without the graphql_schema
    // parameter.
    'default_schema' => 'default',

    // The schemas for query and/or mutation. It expects an array of schemas to provide
    // both the 'query' fields and the 'mutation' fields.
    //
    // You can also provide a middleware that will only apply to the given schema
    //
    // Example:
    //
    //  'schema' => 'default',
    //
    //  'schemas' => [
    //      'default' => [
    //          'query' => [
    //              'users' => 'App\GraphQL\Query\UsersQuery'
    //          ],
    //          'mutation' => [
    //
    //          ]
    //      ],
    //      'user' => [
    //          'query' => [
    //              'profile' => 'App\GraphQL\Query\ProfileQuery'
    //          ],
    //          'mutation' => [
    //
    //          ],
    //          'middleware' => ['auth'],
    //      ],
    //      'user/me' => [
    //          'query' => [
    //              'profile' => 'App\GraphQL\Query\MyProfileQuery'
    //          ],
    //          'mutation' => [
    //
    //          ],
    //          'middleware' => ['auth'],
    //      ],
    //  ]
    //
    // 'schemas' => [
    //     'default' => [
    //         'query' => [
    //             // 'example_query' => ExampleQuery::class,
    //         ],
    //         'mutation' => [
    //             // 'example_mutation'  => ExampleMutation::class,
    //         ],
    //         'middleware' => [],
    //         'method'     => ['get', 'post'],
    //     ],
    // ],
    'schemas' => [
        'default' => [
            'query' => [
                'wine' => App\GraphQL\Queries\WineQuery::class,
                'wines' => App\GraphQL\Queries\WinesQuery::class,
            ]
        ],
    ],

    // The types available in the application. You can then access it from the
    // facade like this: GraphQL::type('user')
    //
    // Example:
    //
    // 'types' => [
    //     'user' => 'App\GraphQL\Type\UserType'
    // ]
    //
    'types' => [
        // 'example'           => ExampleType::class,
        // 'relation_example'  => ExampleRelationType::class,
        // \Rebing\GraphQL\Support\UploadType::class,
        'Wine' => App\GraphQL\Types\WineType::class,
    ],

    // The types will be loaded on demand. Default is to load all types on each request
    // Can increase performance on schemes with many types
    // Presupposes the config type key to match the type class name property
    'lazyload_types' => false,

    // This callable will be passed the Error object for each errors GraphQL catch.
    // The method should return an array representing the error.
    // Typically:
    // [
    //     'message' => '',
    //     'locations' => []
    // ]
    'error_formatter' => ['\Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQL', 'formatError'],

    /*
     * Custom Error Handling
     *
     * Expected handler signature is: function (array $errors, callable $formatter): array
     *
     * The default handler will pass exceptions to laravel Error Handling mechanism
     */
    'errors_handler' => ['\Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQL', 'handleErrors'],

    // You can set the key, which will be used to retrieve the dynamic variables
    'params_key'    => 'variables',

    /*
     * Options to limit the query complexity and depth. See the doc
     * @ https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php#security
     * for details. Disabled by default.
     */
    'security' => [
        'query_max_complexity'  => null,
        'query_max_depth'       => null,
        'disable_introspection' => false,
    ],

    /*
     * You can define your own pagination type.
     * Reference \Rebing\GraphQL\Support\PaginationType::class
     */
    'pagination_type' => \Rebing\GraphQL\Support\PaginationType::class,

    /*
     * Config for GraphiQL (see (https://github.com/graphql/graphiql).
     */
    'graphiql' => [
        'prefix'     => '/graphiql',
        'controller' => \Rebing\GraphQL\GraphQLController::class.'@graphiql',
        'middleware' => [],
        'view'       => 'graphql::graphiql',
        'display'    => env('ENABLE_GRAPHIQL', true),
    ],

    /*
     * Overrides the default field resolver
     * See http://webonyx.github.io/graphql-php/data-fetching/#default-field-resolver
     *
     * Example:
     *
     * ```php
     * 'defaultFieldResolver' => function ($root, $args, $context, $info) {
     * },
     * ```
     * or
     * ```php
     * 'defaultFieldResolver' => [SomeKlass::class, 'someMethod'],
     * ```
     */
    'defaultFieldResolver' => null,

    /*
     * Any headers that will be added to the response returned by the default controller
     */
    'headers' => [],

    /*
     * Any JSON encoding options when returning a response from the default controller
     * See http://php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php for the full list of options
     */
    'json_encoding_options' => 0,
];
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed a few imports and return types, check the updated code:

> app/GraphQL/Types/WineType.php

```
<?php
namespace App\GraphQL\Types;

use App\Wine;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Type as GraphQLType;

class WineType extends GraphQLType
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'Wine',
        'description' => 'Details about a wine',
        'model' => Wine::class
    ];

    public function fields(): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::int()),
                'description' => 'Id of the wine',
            ],
            'name' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'The name of the wine',
            ],
            'description' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'Short description of the wine',
            ],
            'color' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'The color of the wine',
            ],
            'grape_variety' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'The grape variety of the wine',
            ],
            'country' => [
                'type' => Type::nonNull(Type::string()),
                'description' => 'The country of origin of the wine',
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

> app/GraphQL/Queries/WineQuery.php

```
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use App\Wine;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;

class WineQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'wine',
    ];

    public function type(): Type
    {
        return GraphQL::type('Wine');
    }

    public function args():array
    {
        return [
            'id' => [
                'name' => 'id',
                'type' => Type::int(),
                'rules' => ['required']
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args)
    {
        return Wine::findOrFail($args['id']);
    }
}
```

> app/GraphQL/Queries/WinesQuery.php

```
<?php
namespace App\GraphQL\Queries;

use App\Wine;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Facades\GraphQL;
use Rebing\GraphQL\Support\Query;

class WinesQuery extends Query
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'name' => 'wines',
    ];

    public function type(): Type
    {
        return Type::listOf(GraphQL::type('Wine'));
    }

    public function resolve($root, $args)
    {
        return Wine::all();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help @MaartenDev. I also figured it out later. Forgot to update here.

Comment: Thanks @MaartenDev in GraphQL example argument is missing.